# In Angular2, the toolbar(md-toolbar) is not loading buttons when used with a [ngSwitch]

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am creating a toolbar with a menu button on it in this way:

```
<md-toolbar class="header">
<div class="header-wrapper m-x-30 clearfix">
  <div class="logo-container">
     <div class="logo-image align-middle">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <button>
        <div class="menu-image">
        </div>
     </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Now when I use [ngSwitch] to lay out buttons according to type, the button is being created behind the toolbar and is not visible:

```
<md-toolbar class="header">
<div class="header-wrapper m-x-30 clearfix">
    <div class="logo-container">
        <div class="logo-image align-middle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let i of apptoolbar" [ngSwitch]="i.type">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'MenuButton'">
            <button>
                <div class="menu-image">
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2 you can use only one structural directive on the same element. You cannot put `NgFor` and `NgSwitch` in the same element. Use `ng-container` to separate the two.

Change code as following:

```
<md-toolbar class="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper m-x-30 clearfix">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo-image align-middle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let i of apptoolbar">
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="i.type">
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'MenuButton'">
                    <button>
                        <div class="menu-image">
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and tried now again, but still the menu button is not visible.

Comment: In that case, may be its a `z-index` issue. Try setting the `z-index` as 1 for `md-toolbar`.

Comment: Did you already tried to remove the ngswitch? and see if the button is shown then. It is like it is a css error

Comment: Are you sure that that the button is actually rendered and not hidden? Try setting the toolbar background color to transparent. Also check using chrome debugger which elements are getting rendered and the computed style attributes for the button.

Comment: I would also suggest you check removing the `div` with `menu-image` class and put a simple text there instead to see if the button gets rendered.